# Activity templates disappeared from new project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Hi I am new to programming and wanted to create a new project in Android Studio for experimentation.

I wanted to start with the Empty activity which creates the Hello World program but suddently its no longer possible. The window which I get when I click [image: File>New>Project...]

is compleatly different.

Instead of getting the window which lets me select the target API and activity type I get this

[image: I get this]

And from there It only lets me select project name and whether or not it creates the basic main main java method. No XML no nothing.

I dont know what happened

EDIT: I would like to add that I deleted .gardle yesterday once because it was a solution to another problem I had earlier

Comment: Which version of Android Studio?

Comment: Latest(?) version 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by resetting Android studio by deleting .AndroidStudio2.3

Resetted all setting which sucks a bit, but I rather have that.